# how to convert map into key value pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given below:

```
test: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] = Array(
Map(_c3 -> "foobar", _c5 -> "impt", _c0 -> Key1, _c4 -> 20.0, _c1 -> "next",  _c2 -> 1.0), 
Map(_c3 -> "high", _c5 -> "low", _c0 -> Key2, _c4 -> 19.0, _c1 -> "great",  _c2 -> 0.0),
Map(_c3 -> "book", _c5 -> "game", _c0 -> Key3, _c4 -> 42.0, _c1 -> "name",  _c2 -> 0.5)
)
```

How can I transform it to `Key Value` pairs based on `_c0` that only include `Strings`?
like below

```
Key1 foobar
Key1 impt
Key1 next
Key2 high
Key2 low
Key2 great
Key3 book
Key3 game
Key3 name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out

```
test.map(
    _.filter(!_._2.toString.matches("[+-]?\\d+.?\\d+"))
  ).flatMap(
    data =>
      {
        val key = data.getOrElse("_c0", "key_not_found")
        data
          .filter(_._1 != "_c0")
          .map(
            key +" "+_._2.toString()
          )
      }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

# first extract all values which are string
val rdd = sc.parallelize(test).map(x => (x.getOrElse("_c0","no key").toString -> (x - "_c0").values.filter(_.isInstanceOf[String]).asInstanceOf[List[String]]))


val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("key", "vals")

# use explode function to add new rows
df.withColumn("vals", explode(col("vals"))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
test
 .map(row => row.getOrElse(_c0, "") -> (row - _c0).values.filter(_.isInstanceOf[String]))
 .flatMap { case (key, innerList) => innerList.map(key -> _) }
```